# C# AngularJs HttpDelete is not working

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I'm working with C# Web Api and AngularJs. If I add

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
 <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
</modules>
```

The delete request works from fiddler, but when it comes to call it from angularJs i got an error that Options is not define. The options call is done by default by angular.

If I don't add the code form above the HttpDelete does not work. I got a response header like:

```
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, TRACE
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
```

I am using $resource to call the web api from AngularJS. The web.config from web api with removed webDavModule looks like:

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
  </modules>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
    <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
    <remove name="WebDAV"/>
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />    
  </handlers>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="X-Requested-With, accept, content-type" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

The request on google chrome looks like: [this](http://prntscr.com/a1vspg)

Do you have any idea why I've got this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be you are hosting your AngularJs application on `localhost:<port>`. Your Web Api must respond with Access-Allow-Control-Origin containing your `localhost:<port>`.

When you are hosting on different port your browser sends a pre-flight request with HTTP OPTIONS. Web API must allow HTTP OPTIONS verb as well.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

You can also  look inside of Chrome Developer Tools console. Chrome must write an error message in this case to a console. It answers to you HTTP 405 it means OPTIONS HTTP Verb is not allowed, despite it is in response Access-Control-Allow-Headers headers. IIS adds HTTP headers but HTTP 405 comes from your services.

For example, in my OAuth/JWT service implementation I had needed to write logic to respond HTTP 200 on OPTIONS verb on dev environment because of strange constellation of Chrome + `localhost:<port>` and preflight requests.

Comment: Yes I have like this webapi.com and mywebApp.com in web config of the api I do have the options as you can see on this line <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />.

Comment: @Radu Could you please look inside of Chrome Developer Tools console. Chrome must write error message in this case to a console. It answers to you HTTP 405 it means OPTIONS HTTP Verb is not allowed, despite it is in response Access-Control-Allow-Headers headers. Headers adds IIS and 405 comes from your services